# JSon serialization with azure mobile service

Tags: c#, json, json.net, azure-mobile-services

I am using azure mobile service (backend sdk 1.x) and I serialize table objects to Json.

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;
```

I would like to have $type names serialized with each object. This used to work, until i started using Json.net in the other class directly. Now every time i get json from controller, $type property is there but it is empty.

I strongly presume that newtonsoft library is not properly bound to azure web stuff (I did some experiments with custom Json.net serializers and they are not getting called when TableController returns the result to the client).

Any ideas how to troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: *"until I started using Json.net in the other class directly"* -- What "other class" are you talking about?

Comment: need more explanation.